# Import Alamofire using manual installation is not working in iOS swift 3.0 project

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I have followed whole procedure to import Alamofire [using this link](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage#manually)
which includes command line as

```
$ git init
$ git submodule add https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage.git
```

Then I:

- dragged - drag the `AlamofireImage.xcodeproj` in project navigator
- checked deployment target of alamofire project and my application project
- added `AlamofireImage.xcodeproj` for iOS in General tab under embedded binaries.

All seems to be working fine and Alamofire framework got added successfully in target dependency, linked framework and embedded framework in a copy files build phase.

But when I tried to import with `import AlamofireImage` it gives error: "No such module AlamofireImage"

[image: Error message]

Please suggest me what I have missed in installation

Comment: Did you install `Alamofire` too? or just `AlamofireImage`.

Comment: I have installed AlamofireImage framework only

Comment: is it compulsory to install Alamofire framework to use AlamofireImage framework?

Comment: Install Alamofire as well, this should solve your issue.